# Ember.js 2.3 implement @each.property observer on a HasMany relationship?

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-2

Say I have a hasMany relationship Procedure => hasMany Steps, with async:true, and I have a Procedure Component (on the procedure route) called procedure-main, which lists the steps as so:

```
{{#each steps as |step| }}
 {{step.title}}
{{/each}}
```

I need to observe a property on each step (say, stepStatus) on change to the stepStatus on any of the steps. In Ember 1.7, I had something like this on the procedure controller:

```
stepsStatusObserver: function(){
...
}.observes('steps.@each.stepStatus')
```

This was fired on change of stepStatus on any on the steps, and whatever I had in this function was fired whenever the status changed as well. However, in Ember 2.3, I cannot implement this. I have tried with

```
stepsStatusObserver: Ember.observer('steps.[].stepStatus', function(){
...
})
```

but this only fires once when the steps are being listed on the page. When I change the status of one step to a new value, the function is never fired.

How can I replicate this functionality in Ember 2.3?

Note: In my use case, I cannot rely on manually setting off the function inside the observer on the click of a button as it must automatically fire if the stepStatus property was changed on any step.

Comment: It's also possible your scope is wrong, in your template you are using `procedure.steps`, though in your computed property you are referencing `steps`.  Without more information this is just a guess.

Comment: At any rate, `steps.[].stepStatus` is not a working syntax.

Comment: My apologies for the typo: it is steps as |step| on my .hbs, I made a typo in the question. It is fixed in the edit.

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that `steps.[].stepStatus` is not a valid dependent key anymore. You should replace it by `steps.@each.stepStatus`.

Here is a summary of valid and invalid dependent keys in current Ember versions:

- `array` - this observes if the array reference itself changes, e.g replacing the entire array with another value or array such as that `oldValue !== newValue`.
- `array.[]` - this observes both when the array itself changes (above) and when the array length changes (functionally equivalent of `array.length`)
- `array.@each.property` - observes both cases above **and** when `property` of some of the array's items change
- `array.@each.{prop,anotherProp}` - you can also observe multiple properties while specifying only one key. This expands to `array.@each.prop` and `array.@each.anotherProp`.
- `array.@each` - isn't valid anymore, no trailing `@each`. Use `.[]` instead.
- `array.@each.property.property` - Also not valid. Note that `@each` only works one level deep. You cannot use nested forms like `todos.@each.owner.name` or `todos.@each.owner.@each.name`.
- `array.[].property` - not valid anymore. Use `@each` form instead.

Comment: I love the gorgeous detail of this answer; unfortunately, even step.@each.stepStatus is not working. Funny thing is, though, when the route is loaded, for each step, the observer fires once. (before, it only fired once for the whole route). Yet when i change the stepStatus of a step through an action, the observer does not fire.

Here's a followup question: must it be a simple JS array, or should the use case of @each.property work with the default 'subclass of array proxy' that Ember has for its hasMany relationships?

Comment: If it helps, I had the ember debugger tool for chrome on display the whole time, and it definitely registered that the status of the target step had been changed and that it had dirtyAttributes. Even switching the observer to @each.hasDirtyAttributes does not fire on change of stepStatus.

Comment: Ember Arrays may be needed, depending on use case. Can you reproduce the problem on ember-twiddle.com ?

Comment: unfortunately I'm at work at the moment, involved in an issue that needs my immediate attention, but I will update this comment thread as soon as I can twiddle.

Comment: I love using this => array.@each.{prop,anotherProp}

Answer (score 0):

You should still use `@each`

```
stepsStatusObserver: Ember.observer('steps.@each.stepStatus', function(){
...
})
```